# How to Find Code Resulting in Inconsistent Results

Tags: c++, memory

I have a C++ program that processes images and tracks objects in them, using OpenCV.  For the most part, it works well; however the results that I get are inconsistent.  That is, approximately 10% of the time, I am getting slightly different output values and I cannot figure out why.  I do not have any calls to random; I have run valgrind to look for uninitialized memory; I have run clang-tools static analysis on it.   No luck.  The inconsistent runs have one of several different outputs, so they are not completely random.

Is there a tool that will show me where two runs diverge?  If I run gprof or maybe cflow, can I compare them and see what was different?  Is there some other tool or process I can use?

Edit:  Thank you for the feedback.  I believe that it is due to threading and a race condition; the suggestion was very helpful.  I am currently using advice from: [Ways to Find a Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135160/ways-to-find-a-race-condition)

Comment: Setting conditional breakpoints in a debugger?

Comment: some CV processing isn't always consistent, as long as the result is valid, there is no problem.

Comment: Are you using any multithreading? Any floating point math? I assume you are using the exact same inputs each time (on the same machine/compiler/build)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, so that someone can see it.  It was **not** a race condition:

The underlying problem was that we were using HOG descriptors with the incorrect parameters.

As it says in the documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.7/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html), when you call cv::HOGDescriptor::compute, and you pass in a win_stride, it has to be a multiple of block stride.  Similarly, block stride must be a multiple of cell stride.  We did not set these properly.  The end result is that sometimes (about 10% of the time), memory was being overwritten or otherwise corrupted.  It didn't throw an error, and the results were almost correct all the time, but they were subtly different.